# Issue in inserting string

Tags: java, string

I am having string like as follow

```
String first =  "UPPER(substr(con.table_name,1,4)) <> 'BIN$' order by name"

String second = "and constraint_type = 'C' "
```

I have to insert the second  string after  first  string of `UPPER(substr(con.table_name,1,4)) <> 'BIN$'`

My result

`String c = "UPPER(substr(con.table_name,1,4)) <> 'BIN$'` and `constraint_type = 'C'  order by name"`

Comment: So you want us to do something for you without you telling us what you tried and apparently without ever giving credit to those that helped you?

Comment: My question is how to insert string second in string first , but should insert before the(order by name) in string first and after (UPPER(substr(con.table_name,1,4)) <> 'BIN$')

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable so first of all you can't *change* the string referred to by `a`. You need to create a new string and reassign `a` to refer to the new string:

To insert the `b` string before the `order by` part in the `a` string, you could do

```
int i = a.indexOf("order by");
String newString = a.substring(0, i) + b + a.substring(i);
```

The result is

```
UPPER(substr(con.table_name,1,4)) <> 'BIN$' and constraint_type = 'C' order by name
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [java.text.MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html). 
That allows to have a format string (like `UPPER(substr(con.table_name,1,4)) <> 'BIN$' {0} order by name`) formatted with parameters (your param would be `and constraint_type = 'C'`).

Answer (score 0):

If you do have control over a, one of the other answers is probably the best way to go around this.

Assuming you have no control on the contents of string a, you could call a.split("order by"), save the two resulting pieces into two variables a1 and a2 and creating a new string with b between a1 and a2. Something like this (untested):

```
String[] temp = a.split("order by");
String result = temp[0] + " " + b + " order by " + temp[1];
```

Again, I haven't really tested this, but you get the idea.

On another note, it looks like you're doing some bare sql manipulation there. Don't do this, my friend. Your code will be pretty vulnerable to sql injection. Use prepared statements instead.